# Save Different Channels of Ycbcr as seperate images | Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-space

I need to apply some transformations to the individual channels of the Ycbcr color space.

I have an tiff format image as the source and I need to convert it to ycbcr color space. I have not been able to successfully save the different channels as separate images. I have been only able to extract the luminescence channel using this code:

```
import numpy
import Image as im
image = im.open('1.tiff')
ycbcr = image.convert('YCbCr')

B = numpy.ndarray((image.size[1], image.size[0], 3), 'u1', ycbcr.tobytes())
im.fromarray(B[:,:,0], "L").show()
```

Can someone pls help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import Image as im
image = im.open('1.tiff')
ycbcr = image.convert('YCbCr')

# output of ycbcr.getbands() put in order
Y = 0
Cb = 1
Cr = 2

YCbCr=list(ycbcr.getdata()) # flat list of tuples
# reshape
imYCbCr = numpy.reshape(YCbCr, (image.size[1], image.size[0], 3))
# Convert 32-bit elements to 8-bit
imYCbCr = imYCbCr.astype(numpy.uint8)

# now, display the 3 channels
im.fromarray(imYCbCr[:,:,Y], "L").show()
im.fromarray(imYCbCr[:,:,Cb], "L").show()
im.fromarray(imYCbCr[:,:,Cr], "L").show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [`.split()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split) method to split the image into different channels (called *bands* in PIL). No need to use numpy.

```
(y, cb, cr) = ycbcr.split()
# y, cb and cr are all in "L" mode.
```

After you have done the transformations, use [`PIL.Image.merge()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge) to combine them again.

```
ycbcr2 = im.merge('YCbCr', (y, cb, cr))
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, did not know about the split function.